# Lambda helper function with TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I was attempting to redo the below code using key= lambda and ran into this type error and am unsure how to fix it. I believe I'm overlooking something simple, but can't seem to find it. I know the error is most likely coming from my helper function.

```
def search_clinic(search, array):
    new_array = []
    exact_match = []
    partial_match = []
    no_match = []
    # finding mathces and storing them
    for clinic in array:
        if search == clinic:
            exact_match.append(clinic)
        elif search in clinic:
            partial_match.append(clinic)
        else:
            no_match.append(clinic)
    # ordering the stored values to one array 
    for clinic in exact_match:
        new_array.append(clinic)
    for clinic in partial_match:
        new_array.append(clinic)
    for clinic in no_match:
        new_array.append(clinic)
    return new_array
#O(n) linear function   
print(search_clinic('care corp', ['healthcare corp', 'healthcare group', 'care corp', "345gyht", "zelthcare corp", "zelthcare group"]))

# I was unsatisfied with the above solution and went back to attempting to use key= 
def helper(clinic, search): 
    if clinic.find(search) != -1:
        clinic.find(search)
        # use inf to push clinics without search to end of the list
        return float('inf')
def search_clinic2(search, array):
    return sorted(array, key= lambda clinic: helper(clinic, search))

print(search_clinic2('care corp', ['healthcare corp', 'healthcare group', 'care corp', "345gyht", "zelthcare corp", "zelthcare group"]))
```

Comment: Your `helper` returns `None` if `search` is in `clinic`.  Maybe you want to do `key=lambda clinic: clinic.find(search) if search in clinic else float('inf')`?

Comment: Try to test `helper` by itself with some inputs and see if it does what you want. Make sure it works first, *then* use it for sorting. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. The problems in that code are simple typos.

Comment: @Samwise is right. Another way to fix things up would be to modify your `helper()` function so it will never return `None` (and also turn it into a one-liner) via `return index if (index := clinic.find(search)) != -1 else float('inf')`.